# include numbering for reference list Ecology Letters: bst file output.bibitem modification

Tags: bibtex

Would anyone know how I could add numbering to the reference list? Ecology letters changed their style recently, and there does not seem to be a correct bst file around.

I have

> Begon, M., Harper, J. & Townsend, C. (1996). Ecology: Individuals, Populations and Communities. 3rd edn. Blackwell Science, Oxford.
>
> Ferris, C., King, R.A. & Gray, A.J. (1997). Molecular evidence for the maternal parentage in the hybrid origin of Spartina anglica C.E. Hubbard. Mol. Ecol., 6, 185-187.

but I need

> 1.
>
> Begon, M., Harper, J. & Townsend, C. (1996). Ecology: Individuals, Populations and Communities. 3rd edn. Blackwell Science, Oxford.
>
> 2.
>
> Ferris, C., King, R.A. & Gray, A.J. (1997). Molecular evidence for the maternal parentage in the hybrid origin of Spartina anglica C.E. Hubbard. Mol. Ecol., 6, 185-187.

Do I understand correctly one needs to modify all FUNCTIONs such as

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    {
      journal
      "journal" bibinfo.check
      emphasize
      "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
```

Answer (score 2):

I found `ecol_let.bst` designed for Ecology Letters in a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/sckott/NCEASprop/blob/master/ecol_let.bst) ([MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hash `3ef79fc581785a9c2307ecf5276f883a`). The original source of the file is unknown to me. This bibliography style is designed for use with the [natbib](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf) package.

The following [patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29) adds numbering to the list of references when the boolean `MyRefNumbers` is set to true. It uses commands defined in the [etoolbox](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) package. The first change is in `FUNCTION {output.bibitem}` and the second change in `FUNCTION {begin.bib}`. The name of the patched bibliography style file is `ecol_let2.bst`.

```
--- ecol_let.bst    2014-10-17 15:30:44.000129000 +0300
+++ ecol_let2.bst   2014-10-20 15:30:20.592240551 +0300
@@ -671,7 +671,7 @@
   cite$ write$
   "}" write$
   newline$
-  ""
+  "\ifbool{MyRefNumbers}{\stepcounter{MyBibCount}\theMyBibCount.\\}{}"
   before.all 'output.state :=
 }

@@ -1553,6 +1553,7 @@
     'skip$
     { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
   if$
+  "\newcounter{MyBibCount}\providebool{MyRefNumbers}" write$
   "\begin{thebibliography}{" number.label int.to.str$ * "}" *
   write$ newline$
   "\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi"
```

*Without numbers (`ecol_let.bst` or `MyRefNumbers` set to false):*

[image: Output without numbers]

*With numbers (`ecol_let2.bst` and `MyRefNumbers` set to true):*

[image: Output with numbers]

*Example document:*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\newbool{MyRefNumbers}
\booltrue{MyRefNumbers} % comment to remove numbers in reference list
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{begon1996ecology,
  title={Ecology: Individuals, Populations and Communities},
  author={Begon, M. and Harper, J. and Townsend, C.},
  publisher={Blackwell Science},
  year={1996},
  address={Oxford},
  edition={3rd},
}
@article{ferris1997molecular,
  title={Molecular evidence for the maternal parentage in the hybrid origin of \emph{Spartina anglica} {C}.{E}. {Hubbard}},
  author={Ferris, C. and King, R. A. and Gray, A. J.},
  journal={Mol. Ecol.},
  volume={6},
  pages={185--187},
  year={1997},
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{ecol_let2}
\begin{document}
\citet{begon1996ecology}, \citet{ferris1997molecular}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```